# How can you create a Permalink structure on a WordPress site?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

Let's say I want to create a wordpress site that has a folder structure such as:

```
http://www.example.com/cars/
http://www.example.com/cars/red-cars/
```

Yet I want people to be able to comment on both the `/cars/` and `/red-cars/` pages. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

I currently have `/cars/` set as a category and output the category description in the page (to give it the illusion of an actual page and not just an archive listing) and /red-cars/ as a post, and this does accomplish part of what I want to do. But you can't possibly enable comments on an archive page as far as I can tell.

I would ideally like to have `/red-car/` as a post and not a page, as there are going to be plugins used that need posts instead of pages. It's fine if the `/cars/` part is a page, though.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work too smoothly since you are mixing "one of a thing" (which in WP usually means single post) and "many of a thing" (post or term archive).

Since comments are engineered to work with posts (pages are also kind of a post), the closest to this you can *easily* get is probably creating hierarchical Custom Post Type for this. Then `/cars` would be parent post and `/cars/red-cars` child, or something along these lines.

But then you won't really have logical place for its archives (which would be at `/cars/` but then it won't have comments). Depends on your content really.